# ImageMagick Create Image with background and paste 2 images which are resized

Tags: imagemagick

I create an Image with necessary size and background

```
    convert -size 1000x750 xc:'#f4f5f6' /test.jpg 2>&1
```

I need to put other resized image to this new image and then one more for shadows
How to make it in one command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operators [`-geometry`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#geometry) & [`-composite`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#composite) will handle this.

For example...

```
convert -size 500x375 xc:'#f4f5f6' \
        rose: -geometry +100+100 -composite \
        \( rose: -negate \) -geometry +400+200 -composite \
        out.png
```

[image: Paste 2 images]

Comment: Thanks for advice, also how i can resize first and second rose? I try -resize  but it resize the output image. Sorry i found it -geometry 100x100+100+100. It's very pity that imagemagick don't have good manual for such option

Comment: I made     `convert -size 500x375 xc:'#f4f5f6' 10031.jpg -geometry 300x300+100+100 -composite  out.jpg 2>&1` but in out.jpg image from 10031 with incorrect colors ?